# Regular expression for string between any quotation mark

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I want to write a regular expression for a string starts with quotation mark and ends with same mark. It consists of alpha numeric words (e.g. "PL", or 'CS', . . . ).
I thought about [^"].*[^"] , but this is only work for "" these. 
i want output like
input: "CS300"
output: 1 tSTRING
or
input:'a'
ouput: 1 tSTRING

Thanks

my code is

```
%{
int linecounter=1;
%}
%%
\n linecounter++;
(['"])[^'"]*\1 printf("%d tSTRING \n", linecounter);
%%
main()
{
yylex();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write \"(\.|[^"])*\" and \'(\.|[^'])*\' now its working.

Answer (score 1):

Use negated character class and backreference:

```
(['"]).*?\1
```

**Explanation:**

```
(['"]) : matches a single or a double quote and keep it in group1
.*?    : matches what is between
\1     : backreference, same quote as in group 1
```

If your regex flavor doesn't support lazy quantifiers:

```
(['"])[^'"]*\1
```

Comment: When i wrote (['"]).*?\1 or (['"])[^'"]*\1 and my input is "a" or 'b' in the terminal it did not catch and did not print it.

Comment: @M.J.Watson:Please, edit your question and add piece of code. But I have to say that I'm not familiar with flex. This regex works with PCRE regex.